# Cannot understand django user group change signal behavior

Tags: python, django, web-applications, django-users, django-signals

I have a function to receive a signal when users change their group.

```
@receiver(signal=m2m_changed, sender=User.groups.through)
def save_profile(instance, action, reverse, model, pk_set, using, *args, **kwargs):
    print(model, instance)
```

When I change the group of the user with username "test" using the superadmin interface it outputs `<class 'django.contrib.auth.models.Group'> test`. But when I do it using following code,

```
 group = Group.objects.get(name='Customer')
 group.user_set.add(user)
 user.save()
```

it outputs `<class 'django.contrib.auth.models.User'> Customer`.

Because of the above issue I cant use

```
 if instance.groups.filter(name='Customer').exists():
    #Do something
```

inside the `save_profile` funtion. When I change groups using second method it gives `AttributeError at /register/ 'Group' object has no attribute 'groups'` error. How can I avoid getting this error?

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't come up with a reason why this happens but I found a solution for it. I added the following lines to identify which situation it is.

```
if model != Group:
    userObj = User.objects.filter(id = list(pk_set)[0]).first()
else:
    userObj =  instance
```

Then I used the required logic as

```
if userObj.groups.filter(name='Customer').exists():
    #Do something
```